# 2 year 90 day multiple entry visa (China)

Tags: visas, china

I'm planning to go to China. I was wondering if after 90 days I could leave from Shenzhen to Hong Kong and re-enter and stay another 90 days until the visa expires. I'll be staying in Shenzhen.